# Why is boost::filesystem aborting instead of throwing an exception?

Tags: c++, exception, visual-studio-2015, boost-filesystem

I'm migrating some code from VS2010 (using boost 1.55) to VS 2015 (using boost 1.60).

I end up with "Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library" reporting that `abort() has been called` while boost rties to throw an exception. However, I could get it throw other exceptions without any problem (and it used to work with VS2010/boost1.55):

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem/operations.hpp>

#include <iostream>

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    // Stepping to folder:

    try
    {
        boost::filesystem::current_path("B:/dev/msvc2015/vobs_bci/public/tst/base/cppunit/utlfile");
        std::cout << "Worked" << std::endl; // works OK
    }
    catch (...)
    {

    }

    // test throwing upon copy_directory because dource folder does not exist:

    try
    {
        boost::filesystem::copy_directory("s", "b");
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cout << "Caught" << std::endl; // works OK
    }

    // test throwing upon copy because target file already exists:

    try
    {
        boost::filesystem::copy("./test.h", "./copied.cpp"); // works
        boost::filesystem::copy("./test.h", "./copied.cpp"); // should throw and be caught
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        std::cout << "Caught" << std::endl; // never reached...
    }

    std::cout << "Done" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This outputs:

```
Worked
Caught
-> then aborts!
```

With the debugger, I see that abort is called when error function below (in filesystem/src/operations.cpp) calls `BOOST_FILESYSTEM_THROW`:

```
bool error(err_t error_num, const path& p1, const path& p2, error_code* ec,
    const char* message)
{
    if (!error_num)
    {
      if (ec != 0) ec->clear();
    }
    else  
    { //  error
      if (ec == 0)
        BOOST_FILESYSTEM_THROW(filesystem_error(message,
          p1, p2, error_code(error_num, system_category())));  // << Here!
      else
        ec->assign(error_num, system_category());
    }
    return error_num != 0;
  }
```

I checked with the debugger, and I reach `filesystem_error` constructor and can step out of it without any problem, next step (pressed F11 in the debugger, `throw` should now be called), `abort()` gets called.

Strange thing is that when `copy_directory` throws an exception, it also works, and **this does call exactly the same `error` function** in `filesystem/src/operations.cpp`.

Call stack upon abort is:

```
>   ntdll.dll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher()   Inconnu
    KernelBase.dll!RaiseException() Inconnu
    vcruntime140d.dll!_CxxThrowException(void * pExceptionObject=0x000000000019f670, const _s__ThrowInfo * pThrowInfo=0x000000013fd01870) Ligne 136 C++
    test_3rdparty_inprg_boost.exe!`anonymous namespace'::error(unsigned long error_num=80, const boost::filesystem::path & p1={...}, const boost::filesystem::path & p2={...}, boost::system::error_code * ec=0x0000000000000000, const char * message=0x000000013fcf6fb8) Ligne 321    C++
    test_3rdparty_inprg_boost.exe!boost::filesystem::detail::copy_file(const boost::filesystem::path & from={...}, const boost::filesystem::path & to={...}, boost::filesystem::detail::copy_option option=none, boost::system::error_code * ec=0x0000000000000000) Ligne 919   C++
    test_3rdparty_inprg_boost.exe!boost::filesystem::copy_file(const boost::filesystem::path & from={...}, const boost::filesystem::path & to={...}, boost::filesystem::copy_option option=none, boost::system::error_code & ec) Ligne 550  C++
    test_3rdparty_inprg_boost.exe!boost::filesystem::detail::copy(const boost::filesystem::path & from={...}, const boost::filesystem::path & to={...}, boost::system::error_code * ec=0x0000000000000000) Ligne 894    C++
    test_3rdparty_inprg_boost.exe!boost::filesystem::copy(const boost::filesystem::path & from={...}, const boost::filesystem::path & to={...}) Ligne 524   C++
    test_3rdparty_inprg_boost.exe!main(int argc=1, char * * argv=0x00000000003f3cc0) Ligne 35   C++
    test_3rdparty_inprg_boost.exe!invoke_main() Ligne 75    C++
```

But I can't see the source code of `ntdll.dll!KiUserExceptionDispatcher()`nor `KernelBase.dll!RaiseException()`.

Comment: `abort()` raises a signal that causes abnormal termination (`SIGABRT`), not an exception. `catch` statements cath exceptions, not signals. This means that a bug has been encountered, and `abort` was called before the exception launched.

Comment: @mikedu95 The question as I see it isn't why `abort()` can't be caught, but rather why (and perhaps where) `abort()` is being called at all.

Comment: @mikedu95 But when I click "Retry" on "Microsft Visual C++ Runtime Library" popup, it leads me to the `BOOST_FILESYSTEM_THROW` line. Why is this aborting instead of throwing then?

Comment: @hvd you're right, I already have updated my comment

Comment: Reformulated the question....`abort` or `throw`...why isn't it working as expected (`throw`/`catch`)?

Comment: @jpo38 that confirms that one of the functions called at the problematic line encountered an abort, thus `BOOST_FILESYSTEM_THROW` is not executed, because arguments are not yet all evaluated. And maybe it's `BOOST_FILESYSTEM_THROW` itself that has called abort for some reason. Follow your call stack.

Comment: Just look at the stack - you will see exactly where abort is called from.

Comment: @SergeyA: `error` is the last function in the stack (and I know why it's called as ` copied.cpp` exists), `error` is expected here (`abort()` is not). I have no detail on `BOOST_FILESYSTEM_THROW`, it does not appear in the stack as it's a macro....I'll try to see if I can find its source code.

Comment: Are you really sure you have the catch in your code? Are you sure what you are showing us is your MCVE?

Comment: @SergeyA Definitely. I ran this code from a brand new main function

Comment: Possibly the boost library and your program are compiled with incompatible settings for exception handling.

Comment: @MichaelKarcher Did some more tests and updated the post. I can get filesystem throw exceptions correctly, even with exactly the same function being called from `filesystem/src/operations.cpp`. So exceptions definitely work.....only one execution path fails to throw it!

Comment: Except for compiler bugs, the only thing that comes to mind is that some function in the nonworking callstack is inadvertently declared noexcept, or even less likely, declared with an incompatible exception specification.

Comment: Put a breakpoint in `abort()` (the source comes with Visual Studio) and get an accurate callstack. Or press Retry in the abort dialog and disable the code hiding features of VS.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: Just did that, updated the post

Comment: @MichaelKarcher: You may be close. The version of `copy_directory` the code posted reaches does not have `BOOST_NOEXCEPT` flag (line 532 of http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/boost/filesystem/operations.hpp), while the version of `copy_file` reached has it (line 548). If declared with `BOOST_NOEXCEPT`, throwing leads to severous error (and then `abort()`)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`boost::filesystem::copy` is a huge broken mess. The function simply calls `boost::filesystem::detail::copy` with the third argument defaulted to null:

```
  BOOST_FILESYSTEM_DECL
  void copy(const path& from, const path& to, system::error_code* ec)
  {
    file_status s(symlink_status(from, *ec));
    if (ec != 0 && *ec) return;

    if(is_symlink(s))
    {
      copy_symlink(from, to, *ec);
    }
    else if(is_directory(s))
    {
      copy_directory(from, to, *ec);
    }
    else if(is_regular_file(s))
    {
      copy_file(from, to, fs::copy_option::fail_if_exists, *ec);
    }
    else
    {
      if (ec == 0)
        BOOST_FILESYSTEM_THROW(filesystem_error("boost::filesystem::copy",
          from, to, error_code(BOOST_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED, system_category())));
      ec->assign(BOOST_ERROR_NOT_SUPPORTED, system_category());
    }
  }
```

This function in turn is full of invalid dereferences of that potentially-null pointer, and also calls the error code variants of the specific functions that are declared noexcept, passing a bogus reference that resulted from dereferencing the null pointer, which the compiler might well forward as such (remember, we're already in UB land here). These functions in turn take the address of the reference (which typically again yields a null pointer) and call their own detail versions again, which use the error function, which throws if the error code pointer is null.

The workaround:

- Don't use `copy()`, use the concrete function for the type of thing you want if you know it (e.g. `copy_file()`), or
- Use the version of `copy()` that takes an `error_code` and examine the code yourself.

I see you've already posted a bug report. This bug report is correct.

---

Edit by jpo38:

> Don't use `copy()`

Note that this is still the case in boost 1.65.1 recent release. You can prevent developpers from using the function by marking it as deprecated:

Create a file containing:

```
#ifdef __GNUC__
#define DEPRECATED(func) func __attribute__ ((deprecated))
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
#define DEPRECATED(func) __declspec(deprecated) func
#else
#pragma message("WARNING: You need to implement DEPRECATED for this compiler")
#define DEPRECATED(func) func
#endif

...

namespace boost
{
namespace filesystem
{
class path;
DEPRECATED( void copy(const path& from, const path& to) );
}
}
```

And then include it for all cpp file using `/FI` option. Then you'll get a warning if any code tries to use this messy function.

Comment: Other workaround: remove `BOOST_NOEXCEPT` from copy_file and recompile boost? I did that, and it fixed the problem for good!

Comment: @jpo38 That still leaves you in UB land. Just as an example, the compiler could decide that `ec` cannot possibly be null in the first `if` of the function, thus unconditionally call the `bool` conversion of `error_code` with a null this-pointer, and thus really crash. The Visual Studio optimizer appears to be too conservative to do that, but GCC and Clang will. A famous Linux kernel bug was exposed when GCC started doing it, leading to GCC adding a command-line switch for disabling this behavior.

Comment: "belt and braces" I'll do both (recompile + remove calls to `copy`) ;-)

Comment: Using `copy_file` did it for me. Bug apparently still exists in Boost 1.64.0 with VC 2017 (15.3). Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: This bug still exists in 1.67.0. 4 years after it was introduced and 3 years after the bug report in the comments for the other answer was opened, and patch was submitted 3 months ago.

Comment: The same seems to apply to directory_iterator and recursive_directory_iterator. They make a reference from null pointer and then call noexcept method which in turn throws.

Comment: Given that standard C++ now contains a filesystem library, it is not unexpected that the Boost version is not getting much maintenance anymore.

Answer (score 1):

See [the boost source code](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/boost/filesystem/config.hpp). According to that, `BOOST_FILESYSTEM_THROW(EX)` is simply `throw EX`. So there must be a reason, why throw calls `abort()`. That might be the case, when the exception is thrown while another exception is thrown - e.g. in the exceptions constructor.

For the moment my assumption is a bug in `boost::filesystem`. You might consider to file a bug report.

Comment: I would be really surprised to find such a trivial bug in boost...but it's a possibility

Comment: Filled a boost ticket: https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/11914. I'll accept your answer if they say it's really a bug in their code...

Comment: That bug definitely seems to be "accepted"... but not fixed yet?