# Is there a way to test boost libraries?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost

After I found [this bug](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/11914) in `boost::file_system` (see [Why is boost::filesystem aborting instead of throwing an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34793451/why-is-boostfilesystem-aborting-instead-of-throwing-an-exception)), I ended up modifying `boost` source code by removing `BOOST_NOEXCEPT` flag from `copy_file` functions.

Then I changed the version to 1.60.1 (orignal version was 1.60.0), recompiled the whole `boost` project and it works just fine now.

However, as I'm working on a medical device software (`boost` library being identified as a SOUP: Software Of Unknown Provenance), and as I modified it, I'm supposed to prove that my code change has no side effect.

The easiest way to do that is to run a test suite provided with the SOUP. But when I check boost folder, I can find nothing that looks like unit tests (the only `test` folder I found is actually defining `boost::unit_test` module!).

Is there really no unit test available for the boost project that I could compile and run to verify the change I did in the code does not introduce any side effect?

Comment: boost_1_61_0\libs\filesystem\test\ has tests... for the file system you can compile and run them I suppose.

Comment: @SamerTufail: Nice. Any idea if there is a procedure to easily compile and run them all?

Comment: A search for "boost regression tests" revealed this: http://www.boost.org/development/running_regression_tests.html

Comment: Christian - you should put your comment up as an answer.

Comment: @jpo38 Same as Christian, I just wanted to point you to the tests.